# How We Can Avoid 8 Nested Levels Of Conditions In MS Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, power-automate, approval, microsoft-flow

Please assist me. I am pretty new to MS flow.

I currently face a challenge with a flow that has 9 approvals. How can exceed the condition of the nested level?

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

[image: last approval but I cant go further due to nested limit]

Comment: Have you looked into **Switch** control? This doesn't have a limitation how many cases you can have. Take a look at [here](https://sharepointmaven.com/3-ways-to-build-multiple-conditions-in-microsoft-flow/)

Comment: i just dont really have the technical know how to implement this can you assist me please

Comment: Sure, will take a look after my work.

Comment: when will that be ? our time zone might be really different

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately,** you can't exceed the nesting depth for actions, it's a boundary limit!

> For more details about Limits, Please check [Flow definition limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#flow-definition-limits?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973)

So, It mainly depends on your business logic. and you can add child flows as needed!

- Break down the flow into nested child Flow, then
- Run child Flow from Parent Flow.

> Check another case study at [Avoid Nested Levels in MS Flow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-we-can-avoid-8-nested-levels-of-conditions-in-ms-flow2/)

Comment: thank you guys will get back to you

Comment: i need help to understand child flow & parent flow. i'm really new to MS flow not an expert thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements you can create sequential approvals. Check below references for detailed information:

**Microsoft documentation**: [Manage sequential approvals with Power Automate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/sequential-modern-approvals)

**Other Reference**: [MS FLOW APPROVAL FOR MORE THAN 5 APPROVERS IN SHAREPOINT](https://www.theblueflamelabs.com/approval-ms-flow-for-more-than-5-approvers-in-sharepoint/)

**Note**: Flow definition limits are changed. You can check updated limits in below reference link. Currently, Allowed nesting depth for actions is 8. If you requires more nesting depth in your flow then you should consider using **child flows** for your requirements.

[Limits for automated, scheduled, and instant flows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#flow-definition-limits)

**Additional Reference**: [Create child flows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-child-flows)

Comment: thank you guys will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** exceed the condition of the nested level from my point of view.

If you try to put all of these actions into a single flow, it can be difficult to navigate and maintain that flow. You can use child flows to easily manage flows, avoiding flows with hundreds of steps. This approach is especially beneficial if you want to reuse tasks in multiple places in a cloud flow, or even across multiple flows.

For more details about child flow and parent flow, please refer to the following articles:

[Create child flows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-child-flows)

[Helpful tips for using Child Flows](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/helpful-tips-for-using-child-flows/)